# Can I repeat a label/button/variable name in different UIViews? (XCode)

Tags: xcode, swift, uiview, uikit

So I'm working on an XCode project using Swift and I'm wondering if using the same name for (for example) different buttons in different views causes any bugs.

Same with variables, labels, etc.

-Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable with same name but in different class are perfectly fine and there are no side effects. So if you are declaring a button or any other ui element with same name in different class it is safe.

Even if you are declaring outlets in UIViewControllers you are free to create same named outlets in two different UIViewcontroll

Answer (score 1):

If they're not in the same class (file), you should be good.